# Python Threads object append to list

Tags: python, multithreading

I am learning multi-thread in python.I often see when the program use multi thread,it will append the thread object to one list, just as following:

```
# imports
import threading
import time

def worker():
    print "worker...."
    time.sleep(30)

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
```

I think append the thread object to list is good practice, but I don't know why should we do this?

Comment: You keep the thread object so you can join it at the end. Alternately, you can mark it a daemon thread and forget about it.

Comment: Beause you'll need them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is common practice. Taking your example:

```
# imports
import threading
import time

def worker():
    print "worker...."
    time.sleep(30)

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
```

One might want to wait for every thread to finish its work:

```
for thread in threads:  # iterates over the threads
    thread.join()       # waits until the thread has finished work
```

---

**Without storing** the threads in some data structure you would have to do it (create, start, join, ...) **manually**:

```
thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=worker)
(...)
thread_n = threading.Thread(target=worker)

thread_1.start()
(...)
thread_n.start()

thread_1.join()
(...)
thread_n.join()
```

---

As you see (and can imagine): the more you work with the threads, the more "paperwork" would be created if you handle every thread manually. This fastly gets too much of a hassle. Additionally your code would be more confusing and less maintainable.

Comment: Can you pick from this list and stop and start threads as you want? if so can someone tell me how